# how do you use merriam webster dictionary?

Tags: dictionaries

I have a problem using Merriam-Webster dictionary. I can't use it properly.

For example, if we search for `Cramped` in Google it says `uncomfortably small or restricted.`

But I can't find any meaning that matches the Google's translation in Merriam-Webster. Could you give me some tips and advice to use it correctly?

Comment: If you look up **cramped** in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cramped) you will find it listed in the "verb" and "adjective" sections of the entry for **cramp**. If you look it up in [Lexico (Oxford Dictionaries)](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/cramped) you will find a specific entry.

Comment: I'll offer an entirely different tip: Try using [OneLook](https://onelook.com/?w=cramped&ls=a) instead of M-W. It will give links to several dictionaries (including M-W, Macmillan, and Collins), and include links to dictionaries aimed at learners (like [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cramped)). It also often includes a link to [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/cramped), too, which actually lists meanings from four different dictionaries on one page.

Answer (score 2):

It's there, but you need to know how to look for it.

First, since Google is displaying the adjectival definitions, we need to scroll down to the **adjective** definition in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cramped) (the fourth of 4 definitions). There we find:

> **cramp** (*adjective*)
>    : being cramped

Some might say that circular definition is not very descriptive, but we can look at another part of the M-W entry, where we find:

> **cramp** (*verb*)
>    : confine, restrain

When we put those two together, the resulting phrase **being confined or restrained** seems pretty much synonymous with **uncomfortably small or restricted**. After all, Google displays this definition for *confined*:

> **confined** (*adjective*) (of a space) restricted in area or volume; cramped.

[image]